# What do these icons mean in IntelliJ's class hierarchy tool window?

Tags: intellij-idea

What do these two icons mean in IntelliJ's class hierarchy tool window?

a. Class icon with left and right sides greyed out

b. Class icon with square with rounded corners (instead of a circle)

[image: screenshot]

The [reference document](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/symbols.html) doesn't seem to contain these particular icons.

Version: 2016.3.2

Comment: a) it's the new symbol for abstract classes

Comment: b) it's a groovy class - I am guessing their documentation has not been updated to reflect the new icons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class icon with missing parts (vertical lines) represents an abstract Java class.

A squared class icon represents a Groovy class.

The lock represents class in a read-only file.

Comment: It's interesting that the abstract class icon doesn't match the documentation. Maybe it just needs to be updated.

Comment: Yes, it should. Filed https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167383, thanks!